# Why EL function not working in this case?

Tags: function, jsp, el

I am working with Java 1.7, Eclipse Luna and JBoss 4.2.3.

I created a simple Dynamic Web Project named "Test001_WAR". In it:

I created a `StringUtil` class where I define a public static method:

```
package com.srh.base.util;

public final class StringUtil {
    
    public static String notNullTrim(String string) {
        System.out.println("StringUtil.java: notNullTrim(String): string=" + string);
        if (string == null) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return string.trim();
        }
    }

}
```

I created a `myfunction.tld` file where I mapped the above Java method to an EL function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.1" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd ">
    <display-name>Custom Functions</display-name>
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>NMTOKEN</short-name>
    <uri>http://test001.srh.com/functions</uri>
    
    <function>
        <name>notNullTrim</name>
        <function-class>com.srh.base.util.StringUtil</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String notNullTrim(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

I created a `index.jsp` where I use the above EL function for testing. In it I define a string with spaces " abc ", store it in a hidden variable, call the EL function on it and store the return value in another hidden variable, and then after load alert values of both hidden variables:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://test001.srh.com/functions" prefix="fr" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function afterLoad() {
    alert("h_mystring_org=" + document.getElementById("h_mystring_org").value); 
    alert("h_mystring_new=" + document.getElementById("h_mystring_new").value); 
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="afterLoad();">

<%
String mystring = " abd ";
System.out.println("index.jsp: mystring=" + mystring);
%>

<form action="">
    <input type="hidden" id="h_mystring_org" name="h_mystring_org" value="<%=mystring%>">
    <input type="hidden" id="h_mystring_new" name="h_mystring_new" value="${fr:notNullTrim(mystring)}">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I deploy the WAR to JBoss. Then go to URL

```
http://localhost:8080/Test001_WAR/index.jsp
```

It did not work. The function in `StringUtil` class was called but the parameter value it received was not the same as being passed from the JSP.

In the `server.log` file I see:

> 2016-01-10 10:58:37,295 INFO  [STDOUT] index.jsp: mystring= abd
>
> 2016-01-10 10:58:37,298 INFO  [STDOUT] StringUtil.java:
> notNullTrim(String): string=

The alert values were

> h_mystring_org= abd
>
> h_mystring_new=

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the [standard JSTL `fn:trim()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/trim.fn.html) that does exactly that?

Anyway, the JSP EL uses page/request/session/application attributes. Not scriptlet local variables.

Your code would (probably) work if the scriptlet did

```
page.setAttribute("mystring", " abd ");
```

or, if you did the right thing and forgot completely about scriptlet:

```
<c:set var="mystring" value=" abd "/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding that EL uses attributes. When I add `pageContext.setAttribute("mystring", " abd ");` then it work.